# Testing nested AngularJS promises with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-mock

I'm looking to test nested promises and I'm not sure how to go about this.

How would I go about testing a scenario like this?

```
angular.module('moduleA')
   .factory('serviceA', function(serviceB){

  return {
      create: create
  }

  function create(){

    return serviceB.create().then(function(d){

        serviceB.doSomething();

        return $state.go("app.list", { id: d.id }).then(function(){

            serviceB.doSomethingElse();

        });

    })

  };
});
```

Where I would like to test

```
    expect(serviceB, 'create').toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect($state, 'go').toHaveBeenCalledWith("app.list", { id: newId });
    expect(serviceB, 'doSomething').toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(serviceB, 'doSomethingElse').toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Here is my attempt:

```
describe('serviceA spec', function () {

var $rootScope, $state, serviceA, serviceB;

beforeEach(function () {

    $state = {
        go: function(){}
    }

    serviceB = {
        create: {},
        doSomething: {},
        doSomethingElse: {}
    }

    module('app', function($provide){
        $provide.value('serviceB', serviceB);
        $provide.value('$state', $state);
    });

    inject(function (_$rootScope_, _serviceA_) {
        serviceA =_serviceA_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    });
});

it('should create', function(){

    var newId = "555";

    spyOn($state, 'go').and.callFake(function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        deferred.resolve({});
        return deferred.promise;
    });

    spyOn(serviceB, 'create').and.callFake(function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        deferred.resolve({ id: newId });
        return deferred.promise;
    });

    spyOn(serviceB, 'doSomething');
    spyOn(serviceB, 'doSomethingElse');

    serviceA.create();

    expect(serviceB, 'create').toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect($state, 'go').toHaveBeenCalledWith("app.list", { id: newId });
    expect(serviceB, 'doSomething').toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(serviceB, 'doSomethingElse').toHaveBeenCalled();

    $rootScope.$digest();

});

});
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

After each promise you have to call `$rootScope.$apply()` so promises are fullfilled.